# for my understanding i write some code in that i just change increment in diffrent place but it differs the answer in recursion

Tags: c, recursion

why the answer is diffrent for these codes

```
#include<stdio.h>
void recursion(int a,int temp)
{
if(temp==0)
{
    printf("%d ",a);
   return;
}
else
{
    a++;
    recursion(a,temp-1);
    printf("%d ",a);
}
}
int main()
{
int a=5,temp;
temp=a;
recursion(a,temp);
}
```

output:10 10 9 8 7 6

```
#include<stdio.h>
void recursion(int a,int temp)
{
if(temp==0)
{
    printf("%d ",a);
   return;
}
else
{

    recursion(a+1,temp-1);
    printf("%d ",a);
}
}
int main()
{
int a=5,temp;
temp=a;
recursion(a,temp);
}
```

output:10 9 8 7 6 5

Comment: Because `a+1` does something very different from `a++`. The first doesn't modify `a`, the second does.

Comment: I recommend you take the time to learn some debugging techniques, it's essential knowledge if you want to do any kind of programming. Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) together with pen and paper would go a long way to see what the two programs does differently. As would of course use an actual debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. You don't even need to step into the recursive call to see the difference clearly.

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding (by humans) 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Because `a++` is changing `a`, but `a + 1` is not. So when you do `printf("%d ",a);` the new incremented `a` is printed.

```
    // let say "a" were 5 when execution reached here
    a++; // now "a" is 6
    recursion(a,temp-1); // passing 6
    printf("%d ",a); // printing 6
```

While with the other version

```
    // let say "a" were 5 when execution reached here
    recursion(a+1,temp-1); // passing 5 + 1 = 6
    printf("%d ",a); // printig 5 since "a" has not changed
```

Answer (score 2):

In first code 'a++' is used which increases the value of 'a' which is also used in next print statement.

But in another code 'a+1' is used in recursion so value of 'a' is not increased for print statement.

** Also one note .. this seems like an assignment ... please start thinking in step by step way to understand your own code better

Answer (score 1):

in second one ,you are sending `a+1` to function.

In recursive function when you send `a+1` as `int a` argument of function ,it will count as `a` but when it returns , `a+1` will be returned and you will print `a`.

`a++` will increase `a` but `a+1` won't change `a`.

this is reason for different results.